# How to fix android studio first run issues?

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu

I installed android-studio and android-sdk from terminal in Ubuntu groovy gorilla. Now whenever I start android studio it shows an error stating:
"unable to access andrid-sdk add on list"
The changes that I make in set proxy do not work.
So I clicked cancel and then in the welcome page it shows that :
"android studio sdk is missing or corrupted."
Then I when I open the sdk manager, it tells:
"nothing to show"

PS: Android studio worked fine before I reinstalled Ubuntu.

Comment: Someone please help me out!

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Android Studio from Official [website](https://developer.android.com/studio) or JetBrains Toolbox [app](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/).
And don't try to install android sdk and other tools like gradle manually. Leave it Android Studio install them for you. If possible don't use proxy. Because it requires you additional settings. But if you use proxy please refer to this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#setup-proxy) for setting proxy in Android Studio

Comment: But I don't use a proxy.

Comment: In this case totally delete android studio and all its related files. Then try installing again

Comment: Okay. I will try that.

Comment: I have tried everything like reinstalling android studio from apt, downloading from the website and extracting it to the home directory and everything but still i get 3 errors:
1) Unable to access android-sdk on add on list

Comment: Maybe you have got problems with internet connection because accessing add-on list requires internet connection. Check whether or not you are using vpn or proxy @ThilakS